# How do I construct the classpath required to execute a main method in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

We have a very large webapp running in tomcat that has all of the .class files in `tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/classes/`. I need to invoke a main method in one of the classes there, but the classpath is proving to be an issue.

I haven't had to deal with running java on the command-line since University, and every resource I find seems to indicate that Java doesn't support recursive wildcards in the classpath. This is a problem because our application is monolithic with a ton of nested packages.

I will effectively need to add tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/lib/* and tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/classes/**/*

Aside from writing a bash script that will recursively list all files in a tree and add them to a huge classpath environment variable, is there a better way?

We are using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_112. Changing which java we use is not possible at this time.

Comment: A directory hierarchy of class files in normal package layout would allow normal class lookup, you should only need the root. You should need only the jar files and the root of the class file hierarchy.

Comment: Do you want launch another java process like java -jar test.jar ? Why ?

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit rusty on how that classpath works :).

A classpath entry represents a *root*: Whenever the JVM is asked to load any resource (classes are one kind of resource), the JVM will create a path string describing that resource, and will then go through each and every entry in the classpath (so, every *root*), append the resource string, and then check if it is there. First one that's there wins; that's loaded and the JVM looks no further.

When you attempt to load class, say, `com.foo.Whatever`, then the string constructed is: `"com/foo/Whatever.class"`.

Thus, if your classpath is:

```
foo.jar:dir/classes
```

Then if:

```
jar -t foo.jar
```

lists: `/com/foo/Whatever.class`, that item in the jar file is used, and the JVM looks no further. If that doesn't exist, next the JVM will try to check if the file `dir/classes/com/foo/Whatever.class` is there. If yes, that's loaded.

In other words, **you don't want `WEB-INF/classes/**/*`**. You just want `WEB-INF/classes`. All you need.

Modern JVMs do support *, but only for *multiple jar files*: Given a dir filled with jars, each jar is its own root, and * can be used to just add em all. Note, **just** `*`, not `*.jar`, and in unix you have to escape the *, because otherwise bash / your shell application will attempt to expand this, which you don't want. Thus, given:

```
C:\Program Files\yourapp\yourapp.jar
C:\Program Files\yourapp\additionalclasses\com\foo\Whatever.class
C:\Program Files\yourapp\lib\guava.jar
C:\Program Files\yourapp\lib\jdbi.jar
```

You could for example put in the manifest of that app:

```
Class-Path: additionalclasses lib/guava.jar lib/jdbi.jar
```

and then just run it with `java -jar yourapp.jar` and it'll run, and find everything. When using the `-cp` option, you'd do:

```
java -cp yourapp.jar;additionalclasses;lib/* com.foo.yourapp.Main
```

on windows, and on all other OSes, something like:

```
java -cp 'yourapp.jar:additionalclasses:lib/*' com.foo.yourapp.Main
```

Note the single quotes - make sure bash doesn't try to interpret that *.

For preconfig stuff like tomcat, generally you have to configure nothing. tomcat 'knows' that `WEB-INF/classes` is a classpath root for that module and just... makes it work.

Comment: That was extremely helpful, thank you. It has indeed been too long. 7 years since I've done anything of the sort, and even then, it was the most trivial assignments ever.